# Connect Visual Studio Online TFS Server From Visual Studio 2013 with Gmail Account?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am trying to connect Visual Studio Online TFS Server from Visual Studio 2013 with my Gmail account But I am getting,

```
That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different email address or get a new account.
```

My manager send me a notification in my Gmail account to connect visual studio online. But when I try to connect online TFS server it always prompt me `Microsoft Account`. Is it not possible to use Visual Studio Online with a Gmail account?

Comment: you can register Microsoft account with this email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection to Visual Studio Online you must have Microsoft account. If you don't have one you can register it using your any email (for example Gmail).

Answer (score 2):

BTW, Visual Studio Online is now Visual Studio Team Services. You'll need a [Microsoft account](https://www.microsoft.com/account) like @outlook.com or @hotmail.com to use Team Services, but you can use any email to [create your Microsoft account](https://signup.live.com/).

Also, your manager needs to have you appear in Team Services with your Microsoft account, not with the Gmail address they used to invite you. For some reason, Team Services seems to let you use any email to invite people to join.

Reference docs:

- [Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services)
- [Manage users in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/assign-licenses-to-users-vs)